# How to find TFS Label by Date in my asp.net project (Visual Studio Team System 2008)

Tags: c#, asp.net, version-control, tfs, build

I want to get specific version of my solution from TFS.

Loads of checkins and comments happend after that

Right clicking on folder from Team Explorer -> Source control -> Solution Folder and clicking on View History not helping as it is showing all the comments added.

I am trying following

File Menu -> Source Control -> Label -> Find Label

Surprisingly it does not show the date of checkin and show all the labels sort by Name.

[image]

I don't remember the exact date but date column will definitely help me to pick the nearest version.

Now How can I find that label by date.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 5):

Go to Source Control Explorer and right-click on the Branch you want to examine, then select "View History".
This presents with two Tabs: "Changeset" (the Default) & "Labels":
[image]

If you select this one, you 'll get info on the Date & the Comment of the Label.
If you double-click on the Label you 'll get the Changesets that got build within this Label, as well as the version (changeset) of each `$ServerItem` under this branch for the given Label.
Beware that all those fields can be changed after the initial setting of the Label, that's the main argument why Labels aren't recommended in TFS as a means to determine "point in time" (see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2005/11/18/494439.aspx) for a reference), unless you 're absolutely sure none has tampered with it.

Comment: I don't see Labels in the View History window, I am using TFS integrated in my VS Team System 2008. I can see the ChangeSet, User , Date and Comment column only

Comment: Ah, this very well may be for TFS2008, I'm using TFS2010

Comment: wierd, I only see one label, but I have many. I'm using VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use the label command

```
tf labels [/owner:ownername] [/format:(brief|detailed)] 
[/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl] [labelname] [/login:username,[password]]
```

*/format

Displays information about the specified label in one of the following formats:

**Brief**
Includes label, owner, and date created. This is the default.

**Detailed**
Includes also comments, scope, and a list of files and folders associated with each label.*

ex:

```
c:\projects> tf labels
```

you can find the `tf.exe` at the below path

```
C:\...\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
```

more info at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t21wc9ca.aspx

Comment: there is an example on the answer just try it

Comment: You should use tf.exe on the client. Unfortunately I don't remember if brief format includes date, but the detailed one for sure does.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?